# Random field number in protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

A server sends responces in protobuf format. I was trying to recreate definitions (proto file) using protoc "decode_raw" mode and faced some strange structure:

```
2 {
  1: 215647270
  2 {
    215647270 {
      1 {
        2: "30093005"
      }
    }
  }
  5: 360883463
}
```

As you can see, the value of the field #1 (215647270) is some kind of reference to another field. The value (and the branch, respectively) is random. I couldn't find any information in the official Protobuf documentation regarding this "dynamic" generation of the fields.
Does anyone know how to describe this structure with Protocol buffers messages?

Comment: without context, it is pretty hard to guess... those *could* just be unique identifiers such as a db-id, for example, with it being duplicated because reasons. If it wasn't for the `5`, I might have said it could also have been a `map<int, Foo>` (for some `Foo`). Do you have any context you can share with us to help you decipher this? Also, you might find https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode useful - similar concept to `decode_raw`, but (arguably) more friendly to use

Comment: @MarcGravell Unfortunately, I don't have any context. The meaning of these numbers isn't so important to me. The most important is to restore the protobuf definition for this strucutre.The problem is to describe the field which number is the value of another field in protobuf language.

Comment: well, that *isn't* a concept in protobuf **language**, but it isn't uncommon to see that kind of thing in the *data* - denormalization, etc - as an illustration, you might have `int orderId = 1; Order order = 2;` and of course `Order` has it's own `id` field that has the same value that we saw in `orderId`. This is purely an example, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is the protobuf’s [extension](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#extensions) feature and the “random” numbers were just hardcoded by the authors.